# SharePoint Library Search not working as expected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, sharepoint-search

I have a simple document library that contains 8000+ documents in it(invoices).
User are searching with partial characters of invoice number.

***Example:*** Search for "111840-QAP0150969-69" by entering "QAP0150969-69"

***but SharePoint results is 0.***

and the Strange thing is, If I remove  **'-'** from partial Search criteria it returns exact invoice.

Could someone help me to figure it out what is going on here?

**below is the query from Log file and I do not have any errors after these request.**

> eventSearchFlowDone: 0cbe723e-7916-4df0-a9af-e19566e0254c,
>   (path:"http://xxxxxxxxxx/xx//New Binding Unit" OR
>   DocumentLink:"http://xxxxxxxxxx/xx/New Binding Unit/*" OR
>   ParentLink:"http://xxxxxxx/xx/New Binding Unit/*") AND (QAP0150969-69)
>   -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople, Microsoft.SharePointSearchProviderFlow, 64, xxxxxx-APP22.

Comment: Does it return any results if you enter "111840-QAP0150969" ? It is default sharepoint behaviour.

Comment: @harshalgite No. It doesn't, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint's crawl component splits *111840-QAP0150969-69* phrase into three searchable tokens: *111840*, *QAP0150969* and *69* because hyphen character (-) is used as a word breaker by default for English language. This means when you search by any of the tokens (*111840*, *QAP0150969* or *69*) you will get your result back. Querying *QAP0150969 69* will also work because this translates to 'Search for an item which contains tokens *QAP0150969* AND *69*'. Also if you search by entire phrase *111840-QAP0150969-69*, you will get your result back. Same applies for *111840-QAP0150969** (notice the last asterisk character). However, you will not get your results if you enter *111840-QAP0150969* or *QAP0150969-69* because these are only parts of the phrase. It's the same thing if you try to search for terms *kind* or *red* in *kindred*. **QAP0150969-69* will also not work since asterisk is supported only at the end of search phrase in KQL.

Comment: Thank you Slaven!! Understood.